# Vue TypeScript - Top level await throw withAsyncContext error

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs3

The vue official doc says:

#### Top level await

Top level await can be used inside . The resulting setup() function will be made async:

```
<script setup>
  const post = await fetch(`/api/post/1`).then((r) => r.json())
</script>
```

Using an await inside a script setup with typescript throw this error while compiling.

#### The problem

When i try to use an await in my script for triggering the suspense with this code

```
let urls = [
    '/protected/api/indennita'
];

const requests = urls.map((url) => axios.get(url));

await axios.all(requests).then((responses) => {

    // /protected/api/indennita
    let response = responses[0]
    indennitaData.table = response.data

});
```

The compiler throw this error

```
      TS2305: Module '"vue"' has no exported member 'withAsyncContext'
```

Package.json

```
{
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "build": "encore production --progress",
    "dev": "encore dev",
    "dev-server": "encore dev-server",
    "watch": "encore dev --watch"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free": "^6.2.1",
    "@popperjs/core": "^2.11.6",
    "axios": "^1.2.1",
    "bootstrap": "^5.2.2",
    "bootstrap-icons": "^1.9.1",
    "jquery": "^3.6.1",
    "pinia": "^2.0.28",
    "vue": "3.2.47",
    "vue-axios": "^3.5.2",
    "vue-loader": "^17.0.0",
    "vue-router": "^4.1.5",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.7.13"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.17.0",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.16.0",
    "@symfony/webpack-encore": "^4.0.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-typescript": "~5.0.0",
    "core-js": "^3.23.0",
    "regenerator-runtime": "^0.13.9",
    "sass": "^1.56.1",
    "sass-loader": "^13.0.0",
    "ts-loader": "^9.0.0",
    "typescript": "^4.9.5",
    "webpack": "^5.74.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.10.0",
    "webpack-notifier": "^1.15.0"
  },
  "license": "UNLICENSED"
}
```

Comment: Don't post code as image. Ever. You shouldn't require from someone trying to repro having to type package names and versions from an image. It's a blatant lack of respect for their time.

Comment: @tao sorry, i've updated the post with the code

Answer (score 0):

This usually happens with older VUE version, so I would suggest

1 `npm cache clean --force`

then

2 `npm update -g @vue/cli`

Vue CLI 4.x requires Node.js version 8.9 or above to run properly.

Comment: I'am using the latest stable version of vue (3.2.47), @vue/cli 5.0.8 and node v18.15.0

Comment: ok, then clean the cache and install the latest version, also double check that the package receives the latest vue version, you can do so manually.

Comment: Not working, maybe i need some other package for my vue/ts/symfony project?